# Reprojection GeoJSON based on proj4 definition

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson, proj4js

I need to make reprojection(in **Openlayers3** with [**Proj4js**](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)) my **GeoJSON** file in EPSG:4326, by click on the one o the list options in form:

```
<select name="projection" id="select1">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

Every options should be another projection presented by Proj4js definitions.
Like this (**not only EPSG code**):

```
"+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
```

Is possible to change projection this way after choose output projection from the list of options ? When yes , how to make it ? Thanks

Comment: Check [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/how-to-reproject-base-layers-in-openlayers) and this [link](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js) to get things done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just like [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/reprojection-by-code.html). The relevant part is:

```
var newProjCode = 'some_alias_definition'; // like 'EPSG:27700'

// some_projection is a string like '+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
proj4.defs(newProjCode, some_projection);

// tell Openlayers about your new projection
var newProj = ol.proj.get(newProjCode);

// set a brand new ol.View with this projection
var newView = new ol.View({
  projection: newProj
});
map.setView(newView);
```

Comment: I use your code after my code but i see only white screen , and scale line and mouse position not working. Where is the problem ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @THERimaniaTHERimania Maybe you create a fiddle or show your entire code?

Comment: this is the link : [link](http://bcw.4fan.cz) , where you can ind Geojson ant everythin

Comment: @THERimaniaTHERimania Not a chance to understand your code (at link) or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: here is new post with all problem and code : [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191854/why-reprojection-geojson-with-new-ol-view-not-workin)